# Start mulitple tasks using ScheduledExecutorService and remove a task at run time

Tags: java, multithreading

This is what structure of my code looks like

```
 Class TaskA implements runnable {

    void run() {
      if(not leader node) {
          exit this task;
          (never run it again)
         }

       //do stuff
    } 
  };
```

Similarly

```
    Class TaskB implements runnable { ....
    Class TaskC implements runnable { ....


 class Scheduler {
    TaskA memberTaskA;
    TaskB memberTaskB;
    TaskC memberTaskC;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    private ScheduledFuture futureA, futureB, futureC;

    public Scheduler(TaskA a, TaskB b, TaskC c) {
    memberTaskA = a;
    memberTaskB = b;
    memberTaskC = c;
    }

    public void start() {

    exectuor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    futureA = scheduleWithFixedDelay(memberTaskA, 
                           6000,
                           6000,
                           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    futureB = scheduleWithFixedDelay(memberTaskB, 
                           6000,
                           6000,
                           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    futureC = scheduleWithFixedDelay(memberTaskC, 
                           6000,
                           6000,
                           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


    }

};
```

I need the ability to not schedule a task again if "not a leader node" condition is met in the run() method of the task.
One possible approach is to create a separate stopmethod for each Task like stopTaskA(), stopTaskB() and stopTaskC(). Pass object of Scheduler class to  each Task and explicitly call corresponding stopTask() method. 
for eg:

```
stopTaskA(){
futureA.cancel(false);
}
```

This does not look like a very elegant solution.

any ideas for better designs?

Answer (score 0):

How about making your tasks implement Callable instead of Runnable.  They return true if they should continue running false otherwise, but are not actually responsible for canceling themselves (good separation of concerns).

```
class TaskCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {

    /** Returns true if it should continue to be scheduled, false otherwise */
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        if (random.nextDouble() < .1) {
            System.out.println("FINISHED");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("working...");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The referencing/holding class, you "Scheduler" above could look something like this (I wrote it as a unit test for convieneince):

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

@Test
public void test() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    TaskCallable task1 = new TaskCallable();
    TaskCallable task2 = new TaskCallable();
    TaskCallable task3 = new TaskCallable();

    ScheduledFuture<Boolean> future1 = executor.schedule(task1, 100, MICROSECONDS);
    ScheduledFuture<Boolean> future2 = executor.schedule(task2, 100, MICROSECONDS);
    ScheduledFuture<Boolean> future3 = executor.schedule(task3, 100, MICROSECONDS);

    while (future1 != null || future2 != null || future3 != null) {
        future1 = reScheduleIfNecessary(future1, task1);
        future2 = reScheduleIfNecessary(future2, task2);
        future3 = reScheduleIfNecessary(future3, task3);
    }

}
```

where

```
/**
 * Return NULL if the specified future returns FALSE (indicating it is finished). If the specified future returns
 * true then the task is re-scheduled and a new FUTURE is returned.  To facilitate polling this method will return
 * the passed future if it does not answer in 10 ms.
 */
private ScheduledFuture<Boolean> reScheduleIfNecessary(ScheduledFuture<Boolean> scheduledFuture,
                                                       TaskCallable task) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    if (scheduledFuture != null) {
        try {
            if (scheduledFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                return executor.schedule(task, 100, MICROSECONDS);
            }
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            return scheduledFuture;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You are re-scheduling yourself, instead of letting ScheduledExecutorService do that for you -- but perhaps that better reflects your intent anyway-- to run again only if some condition is true.

You could easily generalize this to N tasks.

Comment: thanks, that gave me a good direction.i cant one up your solution as i dont have enough points to do so.